# How to call model file into controller and view in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I am newer in Open cart frame work. I am working to create custom page with file uploading and direct checkout button(just like shopping cart page.)In this page, i already create `(tpl files)` view and controller based on contact form.
Here my controller:

```
<?php 
class ControllerInformationRequest extends Controller {
    private $error = array(); 

    public function index() {
        $this->language->load('information/request');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));  
        $this->load->model('account/request');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('information/request/success'));
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),         
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('information/request'),
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );  

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['text_location'] = $this->language->get('text_location');
        $this->data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact');
        $this->data['text_address'] = $this->language->get('text_address');
        $this->data['text_telephone'] = $this->language->get('text_telephone');
        $this->data['text_fax'] = $this->language->get('text_fax');
        $this->data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
        $this->data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
        $this->data['entry_enquiry'] = $this->language->get('entry_enquiry');
        $this->data['entry_captcha'] = $this->language->get('entry_captcha');
        $this->data['entry_phone']  = $this->language->get('entry_phone');

        if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
            $this->data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_name'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->error['telephone'])) { 
            $this->data['error_telephone'] = $this->error['telephone'];   
        } else {      
             $this->data['error_telephone'] = '';       
        } 
        if (isset($this->error['email'])) {
            $this->data['error_email'] = $this->error['email'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_email'] = '';
        }
        if (isset($this->error['enquiry'])) {
            $this->data['error_enquiry'] = $this->error['enquiry'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_enquiry'] = '';
        }       

        if (isset($this->error['captcha'])) {
            $this->data['error_captcha'] = $this->error['captcha'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_captcha'] = '';
        }   

        $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('information/request');
        $this->data['store'] = $this->config->get('config_name');
        $this->data['address'] = nl2br($this->config->get('config_address'));
        $this->data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');
        $this->data['fax'] = $this->config->get('config_fax');

        if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
            $this->data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
        } else {
            $this->data['name'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $this->data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
        } else {
            $this->data['email'] = $this->customer->getEmail();
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['telephone'])) {
            $this->data['telephone'] = $this->request->post['telephone'];
        } else {
            //$this->data['phone'] = $this->customer->getPhone();
            $this->data['telephone'] = $this->customer->getTelephone();
        }
        if (isset($this->request->post['enquiry'])) {
            $this->data['enquiry'] = $this->request->post['enquiry'];
        } else {
            $this->data['enquiry'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['captcha'])) {
            $this->data['captcha'] = $this->request->post['captcha'];
        } else {
            $this->data['captcha'] = '';
        }       

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/request.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/request.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/information/request.tpl';
        }
        $this->load->model('account/request');
        $this->children = array(
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/content_top',
            'common/content_bottom',
            'common/footer',
            'common/header'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());        
    }

    public function success() {
        $this->language->load('information/request');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title')); 

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('information/request'),
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );  

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['text_message'] = $this->language->get('text_message');

        $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/success.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/success.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/common/success.tpl';
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/content_top',
            'common/content_bottom',
            'common/footer',
            'common/header'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render()); 
    }

    private function validate() {
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 32)) {
            $this->error['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $this->request->post['email'])) {
            $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['enquiry']) < 10) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['enquiry']) > 3000)) {
            $this->error['enquiry'] = $this->language->get('error_enquiry');
        }

        if (empty($this->session->data['captcha']) || ($this->session->data['captcha'] != $this->request->post['captcha'])) {
            $this->error['captcha'] = $this->language->get('error_captcha');
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }     
    }

    public function captcha() {
        $this->load->library('captcha');

        $captcha = new Captcha();

        $this->session->data['captcha'] = $captcha->getCode();

        $captcha->showImage();
    }   
}
?>
```

In view `.tpl` files contain name,Email address, phone,message and captcha images.I just want to stored that data into database,I already create model file in particular locations,
How to call model file (`$this->load->model('account/request');`)...its doesn`t working and its can`t stored database also.How is it possible ?please provide me solutions for this....

Answer (score 1):

To load model from controller use this syntax;

for instance to load opencart folder / catalog/model/catalog/category

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
```

then you can happily call method from that model like below ;

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
```

Comment: Hi..@Erdinç Çorbacı....thank u for ur answer....i already call model following instructions... $this->load->model('account/request');...its doesn`t working properly...could u provided some solutions for this..or any other tutorial for making this...please guide me..

Comment: do you have request.php file in model/account ?  please explain the scenario detailed. what errors do you get , did you open show errors directive ?

Comment: Hi @Erdinç Çorbacı....thank u for ur responsive answer....I`ve that model file which also contain queries..,I want to create custom form just like as contact form stored in db and retrieved in cart pages...

Comment: you should call methods like $this->model_account_request->mymethod(parameters) after loading model i created some model and used that with your submitted code ... it's ok

Comment: Hi @Erdinç Çorbacı...thank u for responsive comment...unfortunately it can`t execute database for this request model...how to call model or how to create model files for opencart....

Comment: please supply all files you use and url path you open in your browser then i will try to build same scenario on my local and try to see what's wrong with your code ok?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27016/discussion-between-display-none-and-erdinc-corbaci)

Comment: Hi @Erdinç Çorbacı....I ve attached my files in chat...(http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27016/discussion-between-display-none-and-erdinc-corbaci) browser url is...[localhost]/index.php?route=information/request.....how to create module for this...or any other change for this...please provide some solutions..